# Haar Cascades don't work well in Dark Lighting

Tags: c++, python, opencv

When I dimmed the lights, I noticed that the face Haar cascade was having difficulty finding my face. (It was not even that dark!)

When the lights are dimmed, how can I track as if the lights were on?

Comment: I suspect that you can also mount infrared lamp onto camera if it is too dark. People don't see infrared lights, camera sensor does. If I remember correctly, several cameras actually offer "night mode" which lights up infrared LED or something.

Comment: You should better share images, that you say 'not even that dark', and the ones before you dimmed the lights..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming lighting conditions are still good enough to distinguish face details, you can try to [**increase brightness**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html) to overcome darkness or [**equalize histogram**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html) to increase contrast.

In general, any recognition algorithms relies on some image features. If the image is too dark or too bright, it's harder for algorithm to find relevant features. Thus, recognition algorithms are **trained** on images with **normal lighting conditions**. You can also train algorithm (such as cascade classifier) on, say, dark images, but most probably this will hit recognition performance a lot. Thus, better way is to normalize dark images before fitting them to the algorithm.

Comment: As I mentioned in first paragraph, increasing brightness and/or histogram equalization should do the trick. Though, it all depends on actual images, so if these 2 options don't work, don't hesitate to come back with a new question and examples of images.